# Adding values from mysql db to select form using node.js in netbeans

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, netbeans, web-applications

I'm very new to this topic and starting to get desperate about finding a solution. 
I want to add data from a mysql database as additional option to a select form on my website using netbeans 8.2 for windows, node.js and javascript. I have looked at tons of material on the internet, but none of them is explaining a detailed usage and setup of node.js in netbeans. I guess I messed up sth during project setup or need to change some options, since I got node.js working when I'm calling e.g.

> "node demo_db.js"

(contains an easy SELECT query) from the command line. I created the project as HTML5/JS Application with Node.js and filled in all required node/npm/node.js paths in HTML/JS and Miscellaneous options.
Node.js and npm are installed.
I have added a picture of my project structure and my code, I hope that makes clear what I want to do. 
I would be very grateful for any advice!

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3ykY.jpg)

My project structure:

Here is my code:

/js/sqlQueries.js:

```
function getAddress() {
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "****",
      password: "*******",
      database: "smoi2"
    });
    var selectA = document.getElementById("showAddresses");
    var i;
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
        con.query("SELECT CONCAT(PostalCode, \" \", City, \" \", Country) AS Address FROM Address;", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (i=0;i<result.length; i++) {
            var row = result[i];
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.value = row;
            opt.innerHTML = row;
            selectA.appendChild(opt);
        }
      });
    });
}
```

and my /index.html file:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/sqlQueries.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="showAddresses" onclick="getAddress()">
            <option value ="zip1">94315 Straubing Germany</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem: I could not get it working and switched to php. That's working great and there are tons of information available.